# Using Racket to Plot Points

Tags: plot, scheme, racket

After spending some time looking at the documentation, searching the web, and experimenting at the prompt, I haven't succeeded at plotting points using Racket. Could someone post an example of how I'd go about plotting (0 1 2 3 4 5) for my x coordinates and (0 1 4 9 16 25) for the y coordinates. I think 1 good example will clear the problem up.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [first example of the doc](http://docs.racket-lang.org/plot/intro.html?q=plot#%28part._.Plotting_2.D_.Graphs%29), and given that the function you want to plot [already exists](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=sqr#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmath..rkt%29._sqr%29%29) in Racket, it's as simple as:

```
(require plot)
(plot (function sqr 0 5 #:label "y = x ^ 2"))
```

[image]

If you just want to see the individual points, this is also taken from [the docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/plot/renderer2d.html?q=points#%28def._%28%28lib._plot%2Fmain..rkt%29._points%29%29):

```
(require plot)
(define xs '(0 1 2 3 4 5))
(define ys '(0 1 4 9 16 25))
(plot (points (map vector xs ys) #:color 'red))
```

which is equivalent to

```
(require plot)
(plot (points '(#(0 0) #(1 1) #(2 4) #(3 9) #(4 16) #(5 25)) #:color 'red))
```

[image]