# Plotting in Racket with names rather than numbers on x-axis

Tags: plot, scheme, racket

I can plot points using following code shown on [Using Racket to Plot Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351792/using-racket-to-plot-points) :

```
(require plot)
(define xs '(0 1 2 3 4 5))
(define ys '(0 1 4 9 16 25))
(plot (points (map vector xs ys) #:color 'red))
```

But how can I plot where x-axis points have names rather than numbers:

```
(define xs '(AA BB CC DD AA CC))
```

Trying it with above code gives a long error message:

```
points: contract violation
  expected: Real
  given: 'AA
  in: an element of
      an element of
      the 1st argument of
      (->*
       ((sequence/c (sequence/c Real)))
       (#:alpha
        Nonnegative-Real
        #:color
        (or/c
         Integer
         Symbol
         String
         (recursive-contract g2149 #:impersonator)
         (cons/c
          Real
          (cons/c Real (cons/c Real ()))))
        #:fill-color
        (or/c
         Integer
         Symbol
         String
         (recursive-contract g2149 #:impersonator)
         (cons/c
          Real
          (cons/c Real (cons/c Real ()))))
        #:label
        (or/c #f String)
        #:line-width
        Nonnegative-Real
        #:size
        Nonnegative-Real
        #:sym
        (or/c
         Integer
         Char
         String
         dot
         point
         pixel
         plus
         times
         asterisk
         5asterisk
         odot
         oplus
         otimes
         oasterisk
         o5asterisk
         circle
         square
         diamond
         triangle
         fullcircle
         fullsquare
         fulldiamond
         fulltriangle
         triangleup
         triangledown
         triangleleft
         triangleright
         fulltriangleup
         fulltriangledown
         fulltriangleleft
         fulltriangleright
         rightarrow
         leftarrow
         uparrow
         downarrow
         4star
         5star
         6star
         7star
         8star
         full4star
         full5star
         full6star
         full7star
         full8star
         circle1
         circle2
         circle3
         circle4
         circle5
         circle6
         circle7
         circle8
         bullet
         fullcircle1
         fullcircle2
         fullcircle3
         fullcircle4
         fullcircle5
         fullcircle6
         fullcircle7
         fullcircle8)
        #:x-max
        (or/c Real #f)
        #:x-min
        (or/c Real #f)
        #:y-max
        (or/c Real #f)
        #:y-min
        (or/c Real #f))
       any)
  contract from: 
      <pkgs>/plot-lib/plot/private/plot2d/point.rkt
  blaming: anonymous-module
   (assuming the contract is correct)
  at: <pkgs>/plot-lib/plot/private/plot2d/point.rkt:47.9
```

How can I make a plot where x-axis has group names rather than numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be doing one of two things. My first guess is that you're plotting some kind of histogram; that is, your XS represent separate categories. In this case, you probably want to use, e.g., `discrete-histogram`. In this case, you'd write

```
#lang racket
(require plot)
(define xs '(AA BB CC DD AA CC))
(define ys '(0 1 4 9 16 25))
(plot (discrete-histogram (map vector xs ys) #:color 'red))
```

If this isn't what you had in mind, let us know.

EDIT: per discussion below, here's how you might update tick labels for certain values.

```
#lang racket

(require plot)

(define current-layout
  (ticks-layout (plot-x-ticks)))
(define current-formatter
  (ticks-format (plot-x-ticks)))

(define my-label-hash
  (hash 1 "AA"
        2 "BB"))

(parameterize
    ([plot-x-ticks
      (ticks (ticks-layout (plot-x-ticks))
             (λ (min max pre-ticks)
               (define default-layed-out
                 (current-formatter min max pre-ticks))
               (for/list ([pt (in-list pre-ticks)]
                          [default (in-list default-layed-out)])
                 (or (hash-ref my-label-hash (pre-tick-value pt) #f)
                     default))))])
  (plot (function (λ (x) x))
        #:x-min 0
        #:x-max 4))
```

Comment: Yes, I was trying to plot a histogram only. Thanks.

Comment: But 2 AA and the 2 CC points are being plotted as separate bars here. How can I plot these as points only rather than histogram, and 2 AA & CC points over their corresponding single x-axis mark. Also, it will be interesting if you could mention what was the second thing you had in mind for this situation.

Comment: Hmm... I see that you're wanting to join the AA results and the CC results, but I'm not sure what you want the resulting graph to look like.  It might be that you just want to see AA, BB, and CC on the X axis, and one or more dots above each label. In this case, you should take a look at the ability to specify custom ticks with "plot-x-ticks", and the example given there. In that case, you'd probably associate each label with a particular x value, then gather the points by x value, then label them as you like.

Comment: I want to see AA, BB, and CC on the X axis, and one or more dots above each label. This page ( https://docs.racket-lang.org/plot/ticks_and_transforms.html ) has methods for numeric, date, time and currency as ticks but not names or categories.

Comment: It has those methods, but it looks like it also provides a more general set of functions to allow you to specify your own. ... Okay, wrote some code for you. see edit to answer above.